# reduce file size as much as low using java

Tags: java, compression

I am developing mobile application using flex 4 , for server communication I am using java Web-services. Actually I need to transfer the files from server to mobile and mobile to server. When I do this operation, my application became very slow. So I planned to compress the file and send. But when I use `GZIPOutputStream` or `ZIPOutputStream` for compression , it's just compress the file as .zip. Couldn't reduce much file size. But I need to reduce the file size as much as low. The file format may be image, video or audio. Kindly anyone suggest some ideas to do this operation using java.

Comment: Image, video, and audio files are probably compressed already.

Comment: Modern multimedia-formats are already compressed very well - you will probably not be able to reduce the size much by additional compression. You could try to reencode them on-the-fly in a smaller resolution/bitrate or stuff like that. Also, are you *sure* that the filesize is causing the slowdown of you application? If your application is well-written, it should be able to handle large files.

Comment: BTW, you can try to set the compression level of the output stream to 9 (the highest available compression rate), but it might not change anything... try to compress the files with your preferred zip manager and check the file is actually compressed. Finally, be careful of the CPU overhead. Compression uses a lot of CPU and you might encounter other slow down on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked us to suggest some ideas. Good,. I think When you transfer the data through Web Services, you must Convert the data as byte array. I think, you receive entire bytes and convert as a file and then Encode/Decode. so when you try to encode some image or video files you can't get reduced file size. so here my idea is, better you can encode the data by pocket by pocket using Base64Encoding and Base64Decoding. Means, Convert the file as byte, encode the bytes and send, and receive the byte and decode and then convert as file. I think this should be helps for you.

Comment: can you suggest me how to do this. I am new to this kind of applications.

Comment: You must google it. there are many Encoding/Decoding Algorithm available. better Choice is Base64Encoder/Base64Decoder.

Answer (score 2):

Most audio, video and image formats are already compressed, so compressing the content again before transfer won't help much. Also, compression can be cpu intensive, so you might just be adding to the problem.

Is it the client or the server that slows down? 
I would suggest that you run a CPU profiler on the slow running application to pinpoint what is going on.

Have a look at http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/profiler-intro.html .